# Pseudo Collapsing Files in VSCode Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose 3 file types: home.html, home.css and home.js.
In order to save viewstate in the explorer panel I could create a folder for each 3 files or better, 3 folders for HTML, CSS and JS files. But instead, is there a way I could consider home.html as 'a folder' to home.css and home.js so I would have something like:

```
+home.html
```

and when I click the Plus sign:

```
-home.html
  home.css
  home.js
```

Maybe an add-on?